# Add 'install' target to 'all' in CMake

Tags: makefile, cmake

I have a CMake project with the following directory tree:

```
build/
assets/
dest/
<other files>
```

`dest` is a directory where all installed files should go:

1. The executable, which goes to `dest/` with a simple `make`, this is controlled with `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`
2. The assets, located on `assets/`, which go to `dest/` after a `make install`.

But I don't want to issue `make install` to copy all files do the `dest/` dir: I want a simple `make` to do this.

In this sense, how do I add the `install` target to the default one (`all`)? Or, is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will execute the `install` target after building `<target_name>` (which could be `all`):

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET <target_name>
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target install
    )
```

Comment: When I try specifying 'all' as the target using this method, I get an error saying "No TARGET 'all' has been created in this directory."

Comment: I get the same tried "ALL", "all", "<all>", and "<ALL>" -- no matter what I get "No TARGET 'all' has been created in this directory."

Comment: This retriggers a build, which recursively calls the post_build, which retriggers build, ad infinitum. Was this tested? I've converted the solution to an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Using the following wont cause recursion. Requires CMake >= 3.15.

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${MY_TARGET} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --install ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --config $<CONFIG>
)
```

Extra : You may want to provide a default (local) install path so this doesn't fail on Windows.

```
if(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "install" CACHE PATH "Default install path." FORCE)
endif()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by using the following macro to generate data dependency rules for the specified target.  These rules require only a `make` and not a `make install`.

The macro maps an arbitrary file from your source tree into a "staging" tree, where each tree structure may be different, and you may optionally rename the file.  The staged data is kept up-to-date, so if you change it in your source tree then it'll be updated the next time you `make`.

```
# Macro used to create dependencies for staging data files (e.g. config files, assets) and keeping them up-to-date.
# The given "source" file is copied (and possibly renamed) to "staged" for the given "target".
#
# It works by creating a rule that creates "staged" by copying "source", then creating a target that depends upon "staged",
# then making the given "target" depend upon the new target. Or in makefile speak:
#
#   staged:  source
#       cp source staged
#
#   targetData1:  staged
#
#   target:  <existing dependencies...> targetData1
#       <existing commands...>
#
# The intermediate rule is used for parallel build robustness.  For details, see:
# http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:add_custom_command
#
# Example:
#   target = myExeTarget
#   source = "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../data/images/bush1.png"
#   staged = "${STAGING_DATA_DIR}/images/bush1.png"
macro(add_data_dependency target source staged)
    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT "${staged}"
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different "${source}" "${staged}"    # Dir(s) will be created if needed.
        DEPENDS "${source}"
    )

    if (NOT DEFINED add_data_dependency_counter)
        #message(status "Setting tmp counter......")
        set(add_data_dependency_counter "0")
    endif()

    math(EXPR add_data_dependency_counter "${add_data_dependency_counter} + 1")
    #message(status "tmp counter is ${add_data_dependency_counter}......")

    set(customTarget "${target}Data${add_data_dependency_counter}")

    add_custom_target(${customTarget} DEPENDS "${staged}")
    add_dependencies(${target} ${customTarget})
endmacro()
```

In your case, usage would be something like:

```
add_data_dependency(myTarget "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/file1.ext" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dest/file1.ext")
add_data_dependency(myTarget "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/file2.ext" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dest/file2.ext")
add_data_dependency(myTarget "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/rename_me.ext" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dest/renamed.ext")
:
:
```

Then whenever you `make`, the files will be copied if missing or out-of-date (assuming that `myTarget` is part of `all`).

Answer (score -1):

The normal way to use CMake is to create a build directory outside your project and all compiled binaries are put there. When you are finished developing and want to install some binaries into your system then you call `make install`. In this way you keep your project source folder free from all compiler generated stuff.

Example file directory structure:

```
my_project/
my_project_build/
```

from my_project_build you call `cmake ../my_project` to generate build files. Call `make` to build it and all binaries will be in `my_project_build`.

Comment: All right, I could adopt this approach too, it doesn't make different in this case. The question is: how to copy the asset files from the `assets/` directory to a destination directory (which I called `dest/`, but it could be `my_project_build` too, whatever) using only `make`? I know how to do that with `make install` (it is just a matter of using `install` commands), but I want to copy those files without issuing `make install`: a simple `make` should do that. Is it clear now?